# iphone unit test case result shows more failures than test cases

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, unit-testing, sentestingkit

I am trying to write some unit test cases for iPhone app. but the results are little weird. I understand the result but want to know how to get actual No. of test cases failed and passed.

```
Executed 24 tests, with 29 failures (0 unexpected) in 71.791 (71.819) seconds
```

This just doesnt make sense. Yes, i Have multiple asserts in one case. it fails more than once, but shouldn't it fail one case only.

```
STAssertNil(var,@"error not nil"); STFail(@"not implemented yet");
```

There , this will say `Executed 1 Tests, with 2 Failures`

How to get `Executed 1 Test Case, 1 Failed` or `Executed 24 Test Cases, 10 Failed, 14 Passed`

Answer (score 0):

The Objective C test framework considers 1 tes to be one method in a SenTestCase. While failures count the amount of assertions.

If you want each test to corresponds to one assertion, you will need to place every assertion into it's own test method.